# angularjs controller is not called and no data is displayed in view

Tags: angularjs, controller

I downloaded the seed project from git. Basically, changed the code in following three files -

***app.js***

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="app">
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MessageController">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

***MessageController.js***

```
angular.module('app').controller("MessageController",function(){
   alert("inside message controller");
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
});
```

When I run http://localhost:8000/app/index.html, it displays `{{title}}` and not the value inside controller.

I am new bie in angular and trying to learn but unable to figure out whats wrong here.

Comment: Its trivial. but do you have the script tags for app.js and MessageController.js in your html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have two different things happening.

**First you appear to have missed adding your javascript dependencies to your html file.**

```
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AngularJS Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="MessageController.js"></script>
</head>
```

***An additional note***

Because you are using multiple files (which is fine), make sure you include the `app.js` file before the `MyController.js` file.

---

**You also need to correctly access the scope.  Even if you add the javascript dependencies you will get a blank page if not bound correctly.**

Because you are using var `vm = this;` format you need to be sure to use the control as annotation

```
<body ng-controller="MessageController as myctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{myctrl.title}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Working Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rapZoDSHx0lN1hJ5Vpuc?p=preview)

Another options is to directly extend `$scope` in your controller.  You could then just have `{{title}}` on your page and it should bind correctly.

```
angular.module('app').controller("MessageController",['$scope',function($scope){
   alert("inside message controller");
    $scope.title = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
}]);
```

Comment: No luck. It displays {{myctrl.title}} now. Infact, I already tried it before.

Comment: Its trivial. but do you have the script tags for app.js and MessageController.js in your html file?

Comment: @Malkus, I wasn't aware that I need to include app.js and MessageController.js in html file. Do I need to include all the modules and controllers like this? I was under the impression that angular detects it by itself.

Comment: @lets.learn Yes you do, the only way to include a javascript file is from your html page.  That being said another way to use angular is with a library called browserify.  But that is a bit more advanced.

Comment: @Malkus, it works by including these app and controller.js file, something I  couldn't even think of assuming angular understands it by itself. Will give browserify a try once I have a flavor of angular. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourapp = angular.module('app', []);
yourapp .controller('MessageController', function ($scope) {
 alert("inside message controller");    
    $scope.title = 'AngularJS Tutorial Example';
  });
```